# pass the parameters using Post API using Alamofire that data need to be added the googleSheet

Tags: ios, swift, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alamofire

That is my GoogleSheetApi if I using pass the parameters using Post API using Alamofire that data need to be added the Google Sheet

This is my Google Sheet API : `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxUMQjh_hEOU_I3R3WMBeoJwTSVIB8-gmBFozVnmno_vu9LQ13hm37_D8BQwB3RAHEP/exec`

code:-

```
 AF.request(urls,method: .post , parameters: parameteers, encoding: JSONEncoding.default ,headers: nil).responseString{ (response) in
        let dic = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data ?? Data(), options: []) as? [String:Any]
        print("Response data -->\(dic ?? [:])")
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            
           print(response)
        print("done")
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print("error: --->  ",error)
        }
    }
    
}
```

output :

```
responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}))
```

if I print `(String(data: response.data ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)` I get output :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Error</title><style type="text/css" nonce="7UMAJK4XlyOlsHCbSXhYvA">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style></head><body style="margin:20px"><div><img alt="Google Apps Script" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png"></div><div style="text-align:center;font-family:monospace;margin:50px auto 0;max-width:600px">The script completed but did not return anything.</div></body></html>
```

I need output :

```
"status": "Success"
```

Comment: And what's your question? what's the output? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: show a minimal example code: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and explain what you want to achieve and the errors you get if any, with your current code.

Comment: Could you print `String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8)`?

Comment: Thanks Mr @Larme it will working

Comment: The message is clear: `The script completed but did not return anything`...

Comment: The script is completed so  post Parameters are update my Google Sheet. Thanks